# Using Excel to count text occurences over two columns

Tags: excel

I have a long Excel spreadsheet with names in 2 columns and I am trying to be able to count the number of times a name appears in column A with a particular name appearing in the same row in column B but I am getting caught up with formulas.

For example, if I have:

```
Col A, Col B
Wilson, Ted
Wilson, Alice
Poole, Frank
Wilson, Ted
Poole, Alice
Frank, Ted
```

I would like to be able to construct a formula that would tell me that Wilson, Ted appears two times.  I've tried COUNTIFS in the following configuration but it returns 0 as an answer:

```
COUNTIFS(A1:B6,"Wilson",A1:B6,"Ted")
```

Am I missing something completely or is Excel just not built for this?

Answer (score 0):

```
COUNTIFS(A1:A6,"=Wilson",B1:B6,"=Ted")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
= COUNTIFS(A1:A6,"Wilson",B1:B6,"Ted")
```

You need to divide each column into their own search.

Comment: I completely missed that.  Thanks very much.